# Notifications causing no dealloc to be called

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, notificationcenter

I am trying to use this within a project: https://github.com/zakkhoyt/VWWPermissionKit

I do not understand KVO/Notification Center as much as I'd like so posting a question.

Basically the init and dealloc for the Permission Manager look like this:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:VWWPermissionNotificationsPromptAction object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                VWWPermission *permission = note.userInfo[VWWPermissionNotificationsPermissionKey];
                [permission presentSystemPromtWithCompletionBlock:^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [permission updatePermissionStatus];

                        if(permission.status == VWWPermissionStatusDenied){
                            [self.permissionsViewController displayDeniedAlertForPermission:permission];
                        }



                        [self checkAllPermissionsSatisfied];    
                    });
                }];
            });
        }];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self readPermissions];
            });
        }];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

If I want to read a set of permissions I would call this:

```
NSArray *permissionsToRead = @[
                                [VWWCoreLocationWhenInUsePermission permissionWithLabelText:nil],
                                [VWWNotificationsPermission permissionWithLabelText:nil]
                                ];
[VWWPermissionsManager readPermissions:permissionsToRead resultsBlock:^(NSArray *permissions) {
// Do something with the result
    }
}];
```

This all works fine. The issue is that the dealloc is not being called, therefore the Notifications are still being called such as the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` being created in the init method.

As far as I can see the Permission Manager is created and not referenced and therefore it just hangs around.

The public method for the readPermssions is as follows:

```
+(void)readPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions resultsBlock:(VWWPermissionsManagerResultsBlock)resultsBlock{
    VWWPermissionsManager *permissionsManager = [[self alloc]init];
    [permissionsManager readPermissions:permissions resultsBlock:resultsBlock];
}
```

A new instance is created and another method is called then passes the resultsBlock back. There is nothing that releases this as far as I can tell. How would I get the dealloc to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `NSNotificationCenter` is retaining the observer object, which is retaining the block that is registered with it, which is capturing your view controller and preventing it from being deallocated.

If you want your view controller to be able to be released then you should create a weak reference (`__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`) to it outside the block and use `weakSelf` inside the block.

You also aren't removing the observer correctly. When you add an observer using the notification center block api it returns an object which is what it is actually adding as the observer and which you need to keep a reference to and pass to `removeObserver:`.

I would suggest just not using the method to observe with a block since it adds more management trouble than it's worth. Use the one that takes a selector instead.

Comment: Do you mean the dealloc isn't removing the observer correctly? The object it adds would be self? Could you elaborate on your last statement please. All I understand is that the permission manager is being created with the notifications each time that read permissions is called but once the returned block is complete its not released at all. I kind of see why but as to fixing it I'm at a loss. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the dealloc isn't removing the observer correctly? The object it adds would be self? Could you elaborate on your last statement please. All I understand is that the permission manager is being created with the notifications each time that read permissions is called but once the returned block is complete its not released at all. I kind of see why but as to fixing it I'm at a loss. Thanks

Comment: Well dealloc isn't getting called, so what it's doing doesn't really matter yet.  But yes, it isn't removing the observer correctly.  The `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` method that you are using returns an object that you need to keep a reference to in order to pass to `removeObserver:`.  The call you are making in dealloc would only remove observers that you added by calling `addObserver:selector:name:object:` passing `self` as the observer.

Comment: Ok I'm with you on that part I think. This repo isn't actually made by me but we can change that part. However isn't the main issue the fact it's retained and dealloc isn't called at all?

Comment: @StuartM The 1st two paragraphs of the answer explain the cause of `dealloc` not being called and how to fix that problem. The 3rd paragraph then points out an additional problem that will appear once `dealloc` is being called.

Comment: I understand the weakSelf point however in my readPermissions example I don't pass the view controller self reference in? I'm clearly missing the point if you could point me towards it that would be great :)

Comment: When you call `[self readPermissions]` in the block that causes self to be retained for as long as the block is retained, which is until the observer is removed (which is never).

Comment: Thanks @dan. Could you also explain the best way to keep reference to the observer being created? To then pass to removeObserver later please

Comment: Thanks for the help. For reference I made a bunch of changes such as: weakSelf references in the return notification blocks, storing the initial permissions manager as an object on the VC instead of allocated each call, added a cleanUp method on the resultsBlock for the view controller which removes all notifications and sets all the relevant references back to nil. Now i get the dealloc called when expected. Thanks