# When Do Blocks Cause Retain Cycles When Using Self?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I am having some memory issue leaks in my app and I am wondering if blocks may have to do with it. I have read that using Self in a block can cause retain cycles, however I have read conflicting information on when this occurs.

From what I understand, doing something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.text = @"test";
        [self doSomething];
});
```

OR

```
[self.dataArrayOfDictionaries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *vd, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       [self doSomethingWithDictionary:vd];
}];
```

Would retain self until do Something is complete, and something like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
 if (data) {
  NSError *err;
    self.myDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  });
 }
```

Would retain self until the download is complete and the table view is reloaded. So, while this code may retain Self longer than is needed, it wouldn't retain it indefinitely, right?

Additionally, I assume this WOULD cause a retain cycle if self is referenced in the block complete, because the block is being retained by self...right?

```
@interface MyViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^complete)(NSData *results);
@end
@implementaiton MyViewController
[self doStuffWithCompletion:self.complete];
```

Where I am not sure about retain cycles is in something like this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserverForName:@"thingDone" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
 self.dataObject = note.object;
 }];
```

I have heard that NSNotificationCenter does NOT retain its observers, but because this function would never really be "completed" like the first two I feel like it would potentially retain Self. Additionally, if i used a weakSelf instead, wouldn't the app crash if the notification is received and self has been deallocated, because weakSelf would be nil?

I have a view controller in a navigation controller that is not deallocating when tapping back/popping it, and I think this may because of a retain cycle. If someone could clarify my understanding on when using Self in a block is acceptable, that would greatly help my code.

Comment: All the things you said about the first 3 snippets are correct and yes the last one causes a retain cycle.  Theres some more information about retain cycles with the `NSNotificationCenter` block API in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866454/notifications-causing-no-dealloc-to-be-called/31866577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where I am not sure about retain cycles is in something like this
>
> ```
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserverForName: //...
> ```

Yes, there can be memory management issues associated with calling `addObserverForName:`. As I explain [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations):

- The observer token returned from the call to `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` is retained by the notification center until you unregister it.
- The observer token may also be retaining you through the block. If so, then until you unregister the observer token from the notification center, the notification center is retaining you. This means that you will leak until you unregister. But you cannot unregister from the notification center in `dealloc`, because `dealloc` isn’t going to be called so long as you are registered.
- In addition, if you also retain the observer token, then if the observer token is retaining you, you have a retain cycle on your hands.

You might want to read the rest of the discussion in my book for actual examples and solutions.

Comment: Fixing this solved my memory leak. Your book also provided me with additional insight. Thanks!